# Issue with .pyc files on remote server

Tags: python, django, pyc

I had a Django project in which I had a file named `itemA.py`. Then I deleted that file and instead created a foldern with an identical name in which I placed files. So the new structure looked something like this:

```
itemA
   itemB.py
   itemC.py
   ...
```

Before that change, when `itemA` was a file, it contained a definition for a serializer which was imported elsewhere.

So after the change, when I ran the project on my local PC, I ran into an error saying:

> ImportError: No module named 'rest_main.serializers.sms';
>   'rest_main.serializers' is not a package

On my local PC, I fixed the issue instantly removing the `itemA.pyc` file. But when I pushed the changes to the remote server, the same trick did not help. I also ran the  `find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -f {} \;` command. But still no success...In bitbucket, all the pyc files are under gitignore...

Comment: did you create a `__init__.py` file to make the folder importable like a file?

Comment: Did not get your point. Yes, it works locally

Comment: normally when you try to import a folder, the folder has to contain a file named `__init__.py` which tells python "hey this folder is importable"

Comment: You made my day

Comment: You made my day bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a file called `__init__.py` to you folder

this tells python that the folder is importable